# Displaying results from user input in flask

Tags: python, flask, output

From what i can gether the script below is accepting user input and running the script, can someone please tell me how i can output the results from the script once its run?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

this is the script itself.

```
def elastic_search(text):
    es = Elasticsearch(['10.0.0.9:9200', '10.0.0.15:9200'])
    word = input(text)
    res = es.search(index="pastebin-*", doc_type='doc', body={"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"match": {"key": word}}]}}})
    return res
```

this is the function that accepts the input and runs the script

```
@app.route('/key', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def key():
    if requests.method == 'POST', 'GET':
       result = request.form['key']
       elastic_search(result)
return render_template('key.html')
```

this is the function that i want to display the results of the script once its been run.

```
@app.route('/result', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       result = request.form
    return render_template('result.html', result = result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0')
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

and heres  the html for the results page -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Results</title>


    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../static/result.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>
  <table border = 1>
     {% for key, value in result.res() %}

            <tr>
               <th> {{ resp }} </th>
            </tr>

         {% endfor %}
     </table>

      </form>
      {% if error %}
        <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
      {% endif %}
      </div>

      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Intel</p>
      </footer>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is key.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Key</title>


    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="styleshee$>

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../static/key.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="text-muted"><Key/h3>
      </div>

      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Please Enter Pastebin Key</h1>
        <form class="form-signin">
        <form action="" method"post">
        <label for="Key" class="sr-only">Key</label>
        <input type="text" name="inputKey" id="inputKey" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter key here" required value="{{request.form.key }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      {% if error %}
        <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
      {% endif %}
      </div>


      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Intel</p>
      </footer>


</html>
```

I understand this is messy but im new to flask and am at a loss trying to whats wrong with the code. Ive read loads of tutorials and none of them have helped me.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what errors do you have? There are many things wrong like using `result.res()` instead of `result` what is `resp`?  where did u get it from? What is key html. Please elaborate the intent what are u trying to do

Comment: It runs but when i enter the key there is no output. Resp was a typo it should have said result. key.html is the page where the user types in the key to run the scrip. If it helps i can edit the post and add it?

Comment: could you paste all code !!  where is key.html  i dont see it.

Comment: It's really not clear how key and result are linked together. How is the data from key getting to result?

Comment: I have added key.html

Comment: I can see `<form action="" method"post">` with no action . update it with 
               `<form action="/result" method"post">`

Answer (score 1):

Given the information which is not clear. i can think this is what you want

```
 # Render key form 
 @app.route('/key', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
 def key():
    return render_template('key.html')
```

You need set `key.html` form to call results route . e.g. `localhost:8000/result`

```
 # then you gather data form 
 @app.route('/result', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
 def result():
 if request.method == 'POST':
   key_data= request.form['key']
   result=elastic_search(key_data)
   return render_template('result.html', result = result)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run('0.0.0.0')
   app.run(threaded=True)
```

your result.html - assuming you result is dictionary returned

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Results</title>


    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../static/result.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>
  <table border = 1>
     {% for key, value in result.items() %}

            <tr>
               <th> {{key value}} </th>
            </tr>

         {% endfor %}
     </table>

      </form>
      {% if error %}
        <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
      {% endif %}
      </div>

      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Intel</p>
      </footer>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `result` will need to actually do something with the return value from `elasticsearch()`.

Comment: Ive made these changes and it still dosent work? I dont get any errors and when i search for the key it accepts it but there is still no output anywhere?

Comment: Check if `elastic_search` returns anything?

Comment: what just the elastic_search function on its own?

Comment: you can print `result` on console? or debug your `elastic_search` in isolation with `key/text` as parameter